# How can I use Material-UI Autocomplete together with react-virtualized?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-virtualized, ui-virtualization

I'm using the [Autocomplete component from Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#autocomplete) in a project. Since I have a lot of options to render, virtualization would be very beneficial. So I started from [the virtualized example](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#virtualization) in the docs with `react-window`. Everything worked great, but the project already has a dependency on `react-virtualized` and I would like to avoid adding a new one that solves something similar. So based on the `react-window` example, I tried to re-implement it using `List` from `react-virtualized`.

**Code Sample**

https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-hypatia-igog8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FVirtualizedAutocomplete.js&theme=dark

**The Problem**

As demonstrated in the sandbox above, it's *kind of* working. What *doesn't* work is the keyboard navigation. You can navigate using the keyboard, but the `Listbox` doesn't scroll to the highlighted value when you navigate outside of the visible elements.

**What I've tried:**

- Overriding `onKeyDown` for the `Autocomplete` component. This however completely overrides the keydown functionality, requiring me to re-implement it.
- Using `onKeyUp` to keep the `onKeyDown` functionality and finding the element with the `data-focus` attribute, and then using `scrollToIndex` on the `List` component. This works for some cases, but if the user holds down the key for a while and ends up on an index outside of the overscan rendered items it breaks.

Does anyone have a good way of using `react-virtualized` to virtualize the options in the Material-UI Autoselect component? Should I be using something other than `List`?

My final resort would be to use the `useAutocomplete` hook and just re-implement the rendering logic, but since I'm only after the virtualization I'd like to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I managed to get it working thanks to an answer in [an issue I opened about this on the Material-UI repo](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18766).

To get the scroll functionality working you need to make sure that the scrolling element has the role of "listbox".

This is an updated example of the code demonstrating a working version:
https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-saha-n9cr1

The only thing changed is extracting the `role` property from the ListboxComponent props and assigning it to the `List` component.

Comment: As an addition to this, the maintainer of `react-virtualized` suggests using `react-window` instead as it's a much much lighter library. In most cases you can use it instead of `react-virtualized`.

Comment: Trying something similar with react-virtuoso - seems I have the `role` prop but still can't get the keyboard presses to work properly. Any other ideas? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69060738/material-ui-autocomplete-virtualization-w-react-virtuoso

Answer (score 4):

```
   /* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
   import * as React from "react";
   import { VariableSizeList } from "react-window";
                                
    const Row = ({ data, index, style }) => {
                                    const elem = data[index];
                                    return (
                                        <div style={style}>
                                            <React.Fragment>{elem}</React.Fragment>
                                        </div>
                                    );
                                };
                                
                                const useResetCache = (data: any) => {
                                    const ref = React.useRef<VariableSizeList>(null);
                                    React.useEffect(() => {
                                        if (ref.current !== null) {
                                            ref.current.resetAfterIndex(0, true);
                                        }
                                    }, [data]);
                                    return ref;
                                };
                                
                                const OuterElementContext = React.createContext({});
                                // eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
                                const OuterElementType = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement>((props, ref) => {
                                    const outerProps = React.useContext(OuterElementContext);
                                    return <div ref={ref} {...props} {...outerProps} />;
                                });
   // eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
    export const VirtualizedList = React.forwardRef((props: any, ref: any) => {
                                    const itemCount = props.children.length;
                                    const gridRef = useResetCache(itemCount);
                                    const outerProps = { ...props };
                                    delete outerProps.children;
                                    return (
                                        <div ref={ref}>
                                            <OuterElementContext.Provider value={outerProps}>
                                                <VariableSizeList
                                                    ref={gridRef}
                                                    outerElementType={OuterElementType}
                                                    className="List"
                                                    height={400}
                                                    itemCount={itemCount}
                                                    itemSize={() => props.rowheight}
                                                    overscanCount={5}
                                                    itemData={{ ...props.children }}
                                                >
                                                    {Row}
                                                </VariableSizeList>
                                            </OuterElementContext.Provider>
                                        </div>
                                    );
                                });
```

//And then use it like this

```
import { VirtualizedList } from "./VirtualListe";                                    
const VirtualizedListComp = (defaultprops: any, ref) => {
return <VirtualizedList ref={ref} {...defaultprops} rowheight= 
{48} />;
                  };
                        
const listboxComponent = props.usevertualization ? 
React.forwardRef(VirtualizedListComp) : undefined;
                    
 <Autocomplete ... ListboxComponent={listboxComponent} .../>
```

Comment: Much simpler solution than the mui website example, and ensures the input props are used!