# Material UI Autocomplete virtualization w/ react-virtuoso

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-virtuoso

I have an almost working implementation of [Material UI Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#autocomplete) with the dropdown list virtualizised with [react-virtuoso](https://github.com/petyosi/react-virtuoso).

The issue I'm seeing at the moment is that when navigating upwards (0:25 in [the video](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/293004/131982848-93cc2eb5-7ee9-4c13-89b1-49ce77d430af.mp4)), the list doesn't move past the topmost item although the component seems to think it moving upwards.

It would seem like internally the list is moving upwards, but the gui isn't updated to reflect this. This is apparent when <kbd>⬇️</kbd> is pressed after pressing <kbd>⬆️</kbd>: it takes as many <kbd>⬇️</kbd>'s as there were <kbd>⬆️</kbd>'s before the topmost item is highlighted again. The expected behavior is to scroll up as with a non-virtualized list, not sure if this is an issue with the react-virtuoso setup or if this is an issue with the Autocomplete component or this setup combining both.

A video of this issue in action can be found in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/28121) or directly [here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/293004/131982848-93cc2eb5-7ee9-4c13-89b1-49ce77d430af.mp4).

Thanks!

edit: here is a codesanbox of the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-r6i2y?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: were you able to fix this? Can you post your working solution incase you have a fixed one?

Comment: Nope, still don't have a working solution. Need to try with MUIv5 to see if it's simpler there

Comment: I have a working sample with react-virtual if you want to try

Comment: Thanks! react-virtual is no longer maintained hence I was trying to get away from it

Comment: I dont think so. The last update was on Jan 21.

Comment: Your right - I was confusing with https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized. Would love to see a working example of autocomplete + react-virtual, perhaps I'll switch to react-virtual

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-c9xduw?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: Does react-virtual support keyboards? (i.e. arrow up/arrow down) Your demo doesn't seem to

Answer (score 1):

I am using Virtuoso for mui autocomplete, just for a simple use case I dont support groups and stuff but is not hard to add to the code. The only thing I do is providing a custom ListboxComponent..the only hack I do is to get the computed maxHeight from the parent as I couldnt figure out how to make the height work correctly on resize

```
const ListboxComponent = forwardRef<HTMLUListElement>(({ children, ...rest }, ref) => {
  const data = children as ReactElement[];
  const localRef = useRef<string>('200px');

  return (
    <ul
      ref={reference => {
        const maxHeight = reference ? getComputedStyle(reference).maxHeight : null;
        if (maxHeight && maxHeight !== localRef.current) {
          localRef.current = maxHeight;
        }

        if (typeof ref === 'function') {
          ref(reference);
        }
      }}
      {...rest}
    >
      <Virtuoso
        style={{ height: localRef.current }}
        data={data}
        itemContent={(index, child) => {
          return cloneElement(child, { index });
        }}
      />
    </ul>
  );
}) as ComponentType<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>>;
```

Comment: Does keyboard navigation work in this example? Do you have a codesandbox demo?

Comment: @Mbrevda It works with `react-window`, so I'd just try to mimic that example with Virtuoso. See https://codesandbox.io/s/9ly4u6?file=/demo.tsx.

Comment: @julis-koronci Thanks chief, I couldn't make it work with any other library and you helped a lot!